# UIViewController - switch presented view controller without flash to presenting one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a presenting view controller that presents a modal like VC, then when the user is done with that modal, I want to transition to another modal, but calling:

```
// we are done.
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

if (self.showOtherContoller)
{
    UIViewController* aVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"someNib" bundle:nil];
    [self.presentingViewController aVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

works, but the presenting base view controller shows for about a second, so it looks all flashy.

Basically I want to replace one view controller with another, not temporarily drop to the presenting view controller.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your modal transition style is CoverVertical.  The first modal slides back down when dismissed, exposing its presentingViewController, then the second modal slides up, hiding the presentingViewController.

You want to change the transition so it appears that the first modal is replaced by the second modal.

Change both view controllers' modal transition styles to CrossDissolve before dismissing the first and presenting the second.  Before dismissing the second, change it to CoverVertical, so it slides down to match the first modal's slide up transition.

Comment: Helped, but there is also a forced(!) rotation of the UI going on, so I think I have some more to do here